# Apply google voice number without mobile number

Tags: google-voice

If I didn't have mobile number, can I apply a Google voice number? when I try to apply a Google voice number, it always ask me the mobile number.

Comment: It seems it's impossible to apply a google voice number without a mobile number, you can apply it firstly then remove the mobile number. but google maybe disable your google voice number after sometime if you didn't use a mobile number for it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this number, which can be any number you have access to, is for verification.  It may be simply to keep people from getting unlimited numbers, since they need a real number each time, and I doubt if it can be the same one.  You do not need to forward number to this number, and I doubt that Google monitors whether the number lives on after you use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [Google Voice FAQ](https://support.google.com/voice/answer/115061?hl=en&ref_topic=1707989), you need an existing phone number. It doesn't have to be a mobile number, but you need to have access to a phone that is not currently associated to a Google Voice phone.

Speculating on my part, this is at least partially to avoid people making large numbers of Google Voice accounts for spam or other purposes.